# remove certain parts of an array

Tags: php, arrays, dropbox

I am making a Dropbox file browser to practice using API's and have come up against a problem. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren("/upload");
    $headings = array_keys($fileMetadata['contents'][0]);
?>
<br /><br /><br />
    <table border="2" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <?php foreach( $headings as &$heading ): ?>
                    <th><?php echo $heading; ?></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach( $fileMetadata['contents'] as &$file ): ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php foreach( $file as &$data ): ?>
                        <td><?php echo $data; ?></td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
```

And I would like to cut out some of the un-needed columns such as rev, thumb_exists etc, etc...  [image]

This is the print_r of the array:

```
Array
(
    [hash] => d023a1738d460f667d383cb4f57bc769
    [revision] => 65
    [rev] => 411389e826
    [thumb_exists] => 
    [bytes] => 0
    [modified] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 20:28:34 +0000
    [path] => /upload
    [is_dir] => 1
    [icon] => folder
    [root] => app_folder
    [contents] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                 (
                    [revision] => 81
                    [rev] => 511389e826
                    [thumb_exists] => 1
                    [bytes] => 1996564
                    [modified] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 21:32:10 +0000
                    [client_mtime] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 21:32:11 +0000
                    [path] => /upload/08-nigellas-chocolate-chip-muffins.jpg
                    [is_dir] => 
                    [icon] => page_white_picture
                    [root] => dropbox
                    [mime_type] => image/jpeg
                    [size] => 1.9 MB
                )

            [1] => Array
                (  
                    [revision] => 79
                    [rev] => 4f1389e826
                    [thumb_exists] => 1
                    [bytes] => 22848
                    [modified] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 21:14:39 +0000
                    [client_mtime] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 21:14:39 +0000
                    [path] => /upload/1376243030_guestion.png
                    [is_dir] => 
                    [icon] => page_white_picture
                    [root] => dropbox
                    [mime_type] => image/png
                    [size] => 22.3 KB
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [revision] => 80
                    [rev] => 501389e826
                    [thumb_exists] => 
                    [bytes] => 54772
                    [modified] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 21:26:19 +0000
                    [client_mtime] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 21:26:19 +0000
                    [path] => /upload/BT_screen_quiz.java
                    [is_dir] => 
                    [icon] => page_white_cup
                    [root] => dropbox
                    [mime_type] => text/x-java
                    [size] => 53.5 KB
                )

           [3] => Array
               (
                    [revision] => 77
                    [rev] => 4d1389e826
                    [thumb_exists] => 
                    [bytes] => 1679
                    [modified] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 20:59:53 +0000
                    [client_mtime] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 20:59:53 +0000
                    [path] => /upload/login.php
                    [is_dir] => 
                    [icon] => page_white_php
                    [root] => dropbox
                    [mime_type] => text/php
                    [size] => 1.6 KB
                )

            [4] => Array
                (    
                    [revision] => 78
                    [rev] => 4e1389e826
                    [thumb_exists] => 
                    [bytes] => 2037
                    [modified] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 21:00:56 +0000
                    [client_mtime] => Wed, 28 Aug 2013 21:00:56 +0000
                    [path] => /upload/signup.php
                    [is_dir] => 
                    [icon] => page_white_php
                    [root] => dropbox
                    [mime_type] => text/php
                    [size] => 2 KB
                )

        )

    [size] => 0 bytes
)
```

please could you tell me how I would go about removing certain coloumns from the table or removing those parts from the array.

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: Have you tried something so far ? Give an example of which part of the array you would like to remove. (Ok, just seen that little line between your screenshots !)

Comment: try adding conditions in your foreach loop to continue if your heading are in one of the unwanted columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We meet again! Since I'm lurking here, I might as well give an answer. For the least amount of effort changing around what you already have and instead of digging through your array to unset values, you can make an array of headings/columns to remove and use it to check your foreach values.

```
<?php
    $fileMetadata = $dbxClient->getMetadataWithChildren("/upload");
    $headings = array_keys($fileMetadata['contents'][0]);

    //Add field names to remove in array below
    $remove = array( 'is_dir', 'client_mtime' );
?>
<br /><br /><br />
<table border="2" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
        <?php foreach( $headings as &$heading ): ?>

            <!-- If statement added below, excludes defined fields to remove -->
            <?php if( !in_array($heading, $remove) ): ?>
                <th><?php echo $heading; ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach( $fileMetadata['contents'] as &$file ): ?>
        <tr>

            <!-- Changed foreach to pull $key as well -->
            <?php foreach( $file as $key => &$data ): ?>

                <!-- Added another if statement -->
                <?php if( !in_array($key, $remove) ): ?>
                    <td><?php echo $data; ?></td>
                <?php endif; ?>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Might not be the prettiest method, but it's probably one of the easiest ways to go about it.

If you want to do it proper, having a recursive function to unset any fields you specify might help. In this case, you could do this:

```
function removeFields( $fields, &$array )
{
    foreach( $array as $key => &$value ) {

        if( is_array($value) ) {

            removeFields( $fields, $value );
        }
        else {

            if( in_array( $key, $fields ) ) {

                unset( $array[$key] );
            }
        }
    }
}
//Still have to define values you don't want
$remove = array( 'thumb_exists', 'is_dir', 'root' );

removeFields( $remove, $fileMetadata );

print_r( $fileMetadata );
```

The above should be done before you retrieve `$headings = array_keys($fileMetadata['contents'][0]);`, that way it doesn't get headings before they are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Being not specific to Dropbox, you can use `unset` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to remove elements from arrays.
For example, to remove the columns `rev` and `thumb_exists` you can cycle on `$fileMetadata['contents']` values (the code is not tested):

```
while(list($key,$value)=each($fileMetadata['contents'])) {
    unset($fileMetadata['contents'][$key]['rev']);
    unset($fileMetadata['contents'][$key]['thumb_exists']);
}
```